# Subqueries: Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4.2

Concept: I tried to retrieve the common pages from 9999 and 1111. See below. (ACF Fiorentia)

[image: PHPMyAdminDatabase]

mysql query: SELECT * from `fb_likes` where `page_id` IN   (

SELECT `page_id` FROM `fb_likes` WHERE `user_fb_id` = 9999)

and `user_fb_id` = 1111

PHP Code:

```
     $temp = FBLikes::where('user_fb_id','=','1111')->get(array('page_id'));
        $tempArr = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($temp); $i++){
            $tempArr = array_add($tempArr, $i, $temp[$i]['page_id']);
        }
        print_r($tempArr);
        $common_likes = FBlikes::whereIn('page_id', $tempArr)->where('user_fb_id','=', '9999')->get();
```

I tried using eloquent. It was not successful.

Steps followed: I executed  the sub query first. Then dumped the data to $tempArr. Then I passed the array $tempArr to main query.

Result: Nothing is saved in $common_likes.

Could you please help me to write the mysql sub queries in single Eloquent statement?  Thank you.

Comment: what is the result of print $tempArr?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Array ( [0] => 334348116596391) is the result of $tempArr

Answer (score 1):

you build invalid array, and you don't have to do that. try to replace `$tempArr` with `$temp` and remove all this code:

```
$tempArr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($temp); $i++){
    $tempArr = array_add($tempArr, $i, $temp[$i]['page_id']);
}
print_r($tempArr);
```

you don't need it.